# Is there a function that can make a string representation of any type?

Tags: ocaml

I was desperately looking for the last hour for a method in the OCaml Library which converts an 'a to a string:

`'a -> string`
Is there something in the library which I just haven't found? Or do I have to do it different (writing everything by my own)?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, if you explain what you want maybe we can give you some workaround. But as said in the answers bellow there are no general solution to this problem.

Comment: Sorry! I have just by now seen your comment. My problem is that I'm searching a general way of printing different types. Taking the tree example: I have different types as values, like an int, a string, a float or a created type. Now I want to print them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a *meaningful* function of type `'a. 'a -> string`, with parametric polymorphism (i.e. a single function that can operate the same *for all* possible types `'a`, even those that didn’t exist when the function was created). This is not possible in OCaml. Here are explications depending on your programming background.

## Coming from Haskell

If you were expecting such a function because you are familiar with the Haskell function `show`, then notice that its type is actually `show :: Show a => a -> String`. It uses an instance of the typeclass `Show a`, which is implicitly inserted by the compiler at call sites. This is not parametric polymorphism, this is ad-hoc polymorphism (`show` is overloaded, if you want). There is no such feature in OCaml (yet? there are projects for the future of the language, look for “modular implicits” or “modular explicits”).

## Coming from OOP

If you were expecting such a function because you are familiar with OO languages in which every value is an object with a method `toString`, then this is not the case of OCaml. OCaml does not use the object model pervasively, and run-time representation of OCaml values retains no (or very few) notion of type. I refer you to @octachron’s answer.

Again, `toString` in OOP is not parametric polymorphism but overloading: there is not a single method `toString` which is defined for *all* possible types. Instead there are multiple — possibly very different — implementations of a method of the same name. In some OO languages, programmers try to follow the discipline of implementing a method by that name for every class they define, but it is only a coding practice. One could very well create objects that do not have such a method.

[ Actually, the notions involved in both worlds are pretty similar: Haskell requires an instance of a typeclass `Show a` providing a function `show`; OOP requires an object of a class `Stringifiable` (for instance) providing a method `toString`. Or, of course, an instance/object of a descendent typeclass/class. ]

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to write a printing function `show` of type `'a -> string` in OCaml.

Indeed, types are erased after compilation in OCaml. (They are in fact erased after the typechecking which is one of the early phase of the compilation pipeline).

Consequently, a function of type `'a -> _`  can either:

- ignore its argument:

```
let f _ = "<something>"
```

- peek at the memory representation of a value

```
let f x = if Obj.is_block x then "<block>" else "<immediate>"
```

Even peeking at the memory representation of a value has limited utility since many different types will share the same memory representation.

If you want to print a type, you need to create a printer for this type. You can either do this by hand using the `Fmt` library (or the `Format` module in the standard library)

```
type tree = Leaf of int | Node of { left:tree; right: tree } 
let pp ppf tree = match tree with 
| Leaf d -> Fmt.fp ppf "Leaf %d" d
| Node n -> Fmt.fp ppf "Node { left:%a; right:%a}" pp n.left pp n.right
```

or by using a ppx (a small preprocessing extension for OCaml) like https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving.

```
type tree = Leaf of int | Node of { left:tree; right: tree } [@@deriving show]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a quick hacky solution, you can use [`dump`](https://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatPervasives.html) from the[`Batteries`](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included) library. It doesn't work for all cases, but it does work for primitives, lists, etc. It accesses the underlying raw memory representation, hence is able to overcome (to some extent) the difficulties mentioned in the other answers.

You can use it like this (after installing it via `opam install batteries`):

```
# #require "batteries";;
# Batteries.dump 1;;
- : string = "1"
# Batteries.dump 1.2;;
- : string = "1.2"
# Batteries.dump [1;2;3];;
- : string = "[1; 2; 3]"
```

If you want a more "proper" solution, use [ppx_deriving](https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving) as recommended by @octachron. It is much more reliable/maintainable/customizable.

Comment: The claim that `Batteries.dump` _works with records and algebraic types_ depends on what you mean by _working_. At that level, it can’t know anything about the names of constructors (`None` is dumped as `0` and `Some 42` is dumped as `(42)`), or of record fields, and it cannot even distinguish between both. All records and algebraic types look the same: tuples with numeric tags. The only thing you have is a basic heuristic that switches to the list syntax when the shape happens to be compatible with that of a list (which can happen by accident: `(42, 0)` is dumped as `[42]`).

Comment: @Maëlan Yeah, that part was kind of copy-and-pasted from the `Batteries.dump` documentation but looking at it now it is a little misleading. Updated the answer and removed the "works with records and algebraic types" part.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving with will create the function of Path.To.My.Super.Type.t -> string you can then use with your value. However you still need to track the path of the type by hand but it is better than nothing.

Another project provide feature similar to Batterie https://github.com/reasonml/reason-native/blob/master/src/console/README.md (I haven't tested Batterie so can't give opinion) They have the same limitation: they introspect the runtime encoding so can't get something really useable. I think it was done with windows/browser in mind so if cross plat is required I will test this one before (unless batterie is already pulled). and even if the code source is in reason you can use with same API in OCaml.