# Any Type ('a) Binary Tree Traversal + Print

Tags: ocaml

I've been trying to write code to traverse and print any binary tree.

However, static typing makes it really difficult.

Here is my attempt. However, it tells me `Error: This expression has type char but an expression was expected of type printable`

In the `example_tree` definition.

I totally understand, 'a' for example is a char and not a printable, even though a printable accepts a char.

How would I make it work without explicitely initializing the node with `Node(Char('a')...)` ?

Here is my code:

```ml
(* Traverse a Binary Tree  *)

exception Error of string

type printable =
  | Char of char
  | Int of int
  | Float of float
  | String of string
  | Other

type tree = Leaf | Node of printable * tree * tree

(* Makes it easy to print any type *)
let formatter (arg : printable) : string =
  match arg with
  | Char c -> String.make 1 c
  | Int i -> string_of_int i
  | Float f -> string_of_float f
  | String s -> s
  | _ -> raise (Error "Error - Unknown Type")

let rec pre_order (node : tree) : unit =
  match node with
  | Leaf -> ()
  | Node (value, left, right) ->
      print_string (formatter value ^ ", ");
      pre_order left;
      pre_order right

let example_tree =
  Node
    ( 'a',
      Node ('b', Node ('d', Leaf, Leaf), Node ('e', Leaf, Leaf)),
      Node ('c', Leaf, Node ('f', Node ('g', Leaf, Leaf), Leaf)) )

let () = pre_order example_tree
```

Comment: Another way to make this work is to have the format function be a parameter to the traversal function. This avoids having a `printable` variant for every type you might want to print.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352035/is-there-a-function-that-can-make-a-string-representation-of-any-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `Node ('c', ...)`. Your current type definition of `tree` just doesn't allow it.

If you eliminate the `printable` and switch to a traversal parameterized by the format function, you can have any type you like inside your nodes. (As in my comment above.)

If you want to stick with `printable`, you can write a function that builds a tree from a simpler description of the characters in it.

Comment: Do I have to rewrite the format function to take `'a` type? I didn't understand very well to be honest

Comment: You would have a different format function for each type that you want to have in your nodes. You can't write a function that does anything very useful with the arbitrary type `'a`. That's a key insight about parametric polymorphism.

Comment: I had this approach in mind, but I would still need to check the variable's type to tell it which function to use right? Or is there an OCaml concept I didn't get yet

Comment: No, you can't check a type at runtime. When calling the traversal function you would supply the function that matches the type in the nodes. Because OCaml is statically typed, you will always know (at the time of writing the code) the type of every tree.

Comment: I see, thank you. So there would be no way in OCaml to traverse a "any" binary tree and print it's content without hard writing the type in advance (or hard writing a specific type function)?

Comment: There's no good way, specifically because there's no good way to write out a value of an arbitrary type. (Note that the OCaml REPL does this anyway even though there's no way. But in some sense you can't write the REPL in OCaml, it's special.) You can also create types, like stripped-down OO types, that are always accompanied by a format function. They're known as "existential types". But I think they are too fancy for the first experiments with OCaml.